# dispalying Grid after the drop down selection is made

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two drop downs on my view. I also have a grid on the view. I want the grid to be dispalyed and populated once the drop down sleection is made and the load button is pushed.

How is it posible in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use an HTML `<form>` containing the dropdown and a submit button. When the submit button is pressed the form will POST the selected value of the dropdown to the controller action which in turn could return a model containing some collection required to display your grid.

So inside the view you would test whether this collection has been initialized (which it wouldn't when initially loading the view) and conditionally include the required display template containing the Grid logic.